# Define the defaults values of winform controls

Tags: winforms, default-value

I have an app(new app) to developpe, changing all values like Font style and TextBox height and other properties of all controls in application is so hard, can i fixing this in the for example app.conf! and how do i express that ?

For example:

- i want to use Font Segio, 11 for all Label controls
- RowHeight by default use 35 for all Grids-View in my application

Comment: If you really need this degree of customizations then you should take a look at WPF instead

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font of the form(or their parent control) and all of its child controls will inherit the font of its parent.

Also you can read the font from config file and set that in you form.
Google "Reading from config file c#" if you don't know that yet.

Comment: I need to change the default value of controls without touche to the code; is it possible?

Comment: For properties that can be inherited you have to set them to their parent like font and then all child controls will be having the same,
For properties like row height their is no way. You have to do it manually.
You can iterate through controls and check their type and set the rowheight property.